# AWX logging to Log Analytics workspace

Tags: azure-log-analytics, ansible-awx

I have AWX congured and want to enable logging to push it to Log Analytics Workspace in Azure, I could not find any help. All points to splunk doco but nothing in regards to Azure LAW. Need help.

I tried running Log analytics agent and configuring ansible.cfg, no luck. Tried pulling using the api endpoints and using the eventhub, did not end well there

Answer (score 0):

I miss some details but as a general answer you should use this module at the end of your playbooks to post result toLog Analytics
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/loganalytics_callback.html